# Nodejs Puppeteer doesn't launch

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to use Puppeteer in NodeJs/express project. I am very new to use so apologize in advance if questions is rather silly.

I have a code in my route:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
router.post('/new_window', async (req, res) => {
  try {
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
     const page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.goto('https://example.com');
     await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
     // await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
     res.status(500)
     console.log(err)
     res.send(err.message)
  }
})
```

I expect that new window will open with example.com page. But nothing is happening and I don't get any errors. 
I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Your code looks ok, have you checked for that screenshot you're saving if it's there ?

Comment: If you want the browser to pop-up just set the headless options to false `await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})`

Comment: @darklightcode. That was it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is you have used router without defining it....and for your requirement there is no need of that and can run smooth with the following code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

( async () => { try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://example.com");
    await page.screenshot( {path: 'example.png'});    
    await browser.close();
} catch(err) { console.log(err); }
    
})();
```